# Vary azure devops pipeline agent by parameter

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'd like to use a parameter to enable the pipeline to switch between running on dedicated agents or an azure host by switching between

pool:
name: Default

and

pool:
vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

```
parameters:
- name: custom_agent
  displayName: Use Custom Agent
  type: boolean
  default: true

    pool:
    ${{ if  eq(parameters.custom_agent, True) }}:
      name: ${{ parameters.agent_pool }}
    ${{ if  eq(parameters.custom_agent, False) }}:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
```

I've tried various variations but keep getting the error 'A template expression is not allowed in this context'

Am i missing something?, feels like this shouldn't be that hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At present, we can not use this script to help us switch the pool. But we have a work around to help us. We can use the Parameters to select a template at runtime, refer [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#parameters-to-select-a-template-at-runtime). We can set different agent in the template then select the temp at runtime.
So on my side, I create a demo to help you know:

**Main yaml:**

```
parameters:
  - name: custom_agent
    displayName: Use Custom Agent
    type: boolean
    default: true
  - name: image
    type: string
    default: default

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: templates
      type: git
      name: Tech-Talk/template

trigger: none
stages:
  - ${{if eq(parameters.custom_agent, True) }}:
    - template: temp.yaml@templates 
  - ${{ if not(eq(parameters.custom_agent, True)) }}:
    - template: temp2.yaml@templates
```

**temp.yaml by using self-agent:**

```
stages:
  - stage:
    pool: 'default'          
    jobs:
    - job: READ
      displayName: Reading Parameters      
      steps:
      - powershell: echo "self-agent"
```

**temp2.yaml by using the hosted agent:**

```
stages:
  - stage:      
    jobs:
    - job: READ
      displayName: Reading Parameters      
      pool:
        # vmImage: windows-latest
        vmImage: ubuntu-20.04
      steps:
      - powershell: echo "self-agent"
```

**Note:** You can use the key word 'pool' both in the job and stage.

Comment: Thanks for this, I was exploring something similar but it felt a very long winded way to be able to manage the pool via a parameter. It also means that although there is only really one script step it needs to be maintained in two files. This is perhaps the only way but felt I might have missed something more obvious

Answer (score 0):

I found that wrapping the `pool` in an if block works

```yaml
parameters:
- name: vmImageName
  type: string
  default: 'ubuntu-latest'

- name: agentPoolName
  type: string
  default: null

jobs:  
  - job: Docker
    ${{ if ne(parameters.agentPoolName, 'null')}}:
      pool:
        name: ${{ parameters.agentPoolName }}
    ${{ if eq(parameters.agentPoolName, 'null')}}:
      pool:
        vmImage: ${{ parameters.vmImageName }}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me.

```yaml
parameters:
- name: vmImageName
  type: string
  default: 'windows-2022'

- name: agentPoolName
  type: string
  default: null

jobs:
  - job: Primary
    pool:
      ${{ if ne(parameters.agentPoolName, 'null')}}:
        name: ${{ parameters.agentPoolName }}
      ${{ if eq(parameters.agentPoolName, 'null')}}:
        vmImage: ${{ parameters.vmImageName }}
    steps:
      - task: CmdLine@2
        inputs:
          script: 'echo Hello world'
```